# Mongodb : An error occurred while loading navigation: Invalid UTF-8 string in BSON document

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, navigation, bson

I installed MongoDB Compass, and I get error message “An error occurred while loading navigation: Invalid UTF-8 string in BSON document”. I can't visualize my data.

Version MongoDB 5.0.3(current)

Windows 10

I tried reinstalling a different version of MongoDB but it didn't help.

I download it on another other computer of the same configuration, everything seems to work.
What could have happened?

P.S. Console commands work without problem.
[This is what I see after i click on connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6tz5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with MongoDB Compass and fix it by doing the following:

1. Uninstall the version of MongoDB Compass that comes by default with the Mongo installation.
2. I downloaded one of the older versions.

I leave you the link so you can download the previous version which has managed to correct this error.
https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass-1.21.2-win32-x64.zip

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with the same MongoDB Compass version shared by Wlogz (1.21.2).
The link is in the previous comment...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem, mine got solved simply by changing the hostname or name of my computer. Happened that my name has an accent "Martín"; removing it completely solves the issue.